# Boolean indexing a DataFrame in pandas an replacing the columns with elements of a Series where condition is True

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
>>>df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))
>>>df
             0         1         2
   0 -0.685692  0.180900  0.652838
   1  0.484584 -0.441004 -1.617281
   2 -0.665110  1.196987 -0.133439
```

I want to replace all elements of a row that are >0 for example with the corresponding element of a Series `s` of length `df.shape[0]`:

```
>>>s = pd.Series((3,4,5))
>>>s
   0    3
   1    4
   2    5
   dtype: int64
```

It works with:

```
>>>df.where(df<=0, s, axis=0)
             0         1         2
   0 -0.685692  3.000000  3.000000
   1  4.000000 -0.441004 -1.617281
   2 -0.665110  5.000000 -0.133439
```

But my real criteria is quite complex so I want to state the criteria in a positive way (instead of reversing the criteria like in the `where`statement above with `<=0` instead of `>0` way with:

```
>>>df[df>0] = s
```

But instead of a result I get an Error that the `axis` is missing. How can I specify the axis in the statement above?

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 97, line 1
  File "/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2297, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_frame(key, value)
  File "/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2335, in _setitem_frame
    self.where(-key, value, inplace=True)
  File "/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3940, in where
    fill_value=np.nan)
  File "/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2680, in align
    fill_axis=fill_axis, broadcast_axis=broadcast_axis)
  File "/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3784, in align
    fill_axis=fill_axis)
  File "/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3870, in _align_series
    raise ValueError('Must specify axis=0 or 1')
ValueError: Must specify axis=0 or 1
```

Comment: It seems as bug. I think [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) is internally convert to `where`. So you can use `df.where(df>0, s, axis=0)` only.

Comment: @jezrael: unfortunately that does not work, because s is replaced where not(df>0). That is no problem in this example, as I wrote, but my real criteria is much more complex, and formulating it the other way round does add an additional layer of complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is obvious:

```
>>>df.where(~(df>0),s)
```

You simply have to negate the condition. Sometimes when sitting too long in front of the screen one tends to get blind !